# How do I get my pre-order bonus content in AC 3?

Tags: pc, assassins-creed-3

I've pre-ordered the [AC III deluxe edition](http://shop.ubi.com/store/ubiemea/en_IE/pd/ThemeID.8605700/productID.252308600/Assassins-Creed-III-Deluxe-Edition.html) and now It's ready. I've installed it, but it seems that I only installed the game without the added contents of the deluxe edition,

I didn't receive any codes or instructions on installing the extra contents, only a link to the download manager, and links to download Washington's notebook and the ST. How do I get the extra content, and how do I use my season pass (when DLCs arrive)?

Comment: Assuming you are talking about the Deluxe Edition for PC, added the PC tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer,The code for the game is also the code for the DLC's.

In single player, go to the extras, then to redeem code, and enter the key for the game.